# Least squares estimator in a time series $\{Y_t\}$

Tags: time-series, self-study, estimation, least-squares

> Let $\{Y_t\}$ be a stochastic process such that
>   $$\begin{cases}Y_t=\beta x_t+z_t\\z_t=\varepsilon_t+\theta
>  \varepsilon_{t-1}\\\varepsilon_t\sim WN(0,1)\end{cases}$$
>
> where $WN$ means white noise (it's not a probability distribution) with $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_t]=0$ and
>   $\text{Var}(\varepsilon_t)=1$. The $x_t$ values are constants not random. Find
>   the least squares estimator of $\beta$ and the variance of estimator.

**Question:** Is the following correct?

**Attempt:** What I did is
$$Q=\sum (y_t-(\beta x_t+z_t))^2=\sum y_t^2-2y_t(\beta x_t+z_t)+(\beta x_t+z_t)^2$$
$$=\sum y_t^2-2y_t\beta x_t-2y_tz_t+\beta^2x_t^2+2\beta x_tz_t+z_t^2$$
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta}=\sum -2y_tx_t+2\beta\sum x_t^2-\sum x_tz_t=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum y_tx_t-\sum x_tz_t}{\sum x_t^2}$$

Taking the second derivative
$$\frac{\partial^2Q}{\partial\beta\partial\beta}=\sum x_t^2>0\qquad \forall t$$

then $\hat{\beta}$ is a minimum point and is the least square estimator.

$$\text{Var}(\hat{\beta})=\text{Var}\left(\frac{\sum y_tx_t-\sum x_tz_t}{\sum x_t^2}\right)=\frac{1}{(\sum x_t^2)^2}\text{Var}\left(\sum y_tx_t-\sum x_tz_t\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{(\sum x_t^2)^2}\big(\text{Var}\left(\sum y_tx_t\right)+\text{Var}\left(\sum x_tz_t\right)-2\text{Cov}\left(\sum y_tx_t,\sum x_tz_t)\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{(\sum x_t^2)^2}\Big(\text{Var}\Big[\sum \beta x_t\Big(\varepsilon_t+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}\Big)\Big]+\text{Var}\Big[\sum x_t\Big(\varepsilon_t+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}\Big)\Big]-2\text{Cov}\Big[\sum \beta x_t\Big(\varepsilon_t+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}\Big),\sum x_t\Big(\varepsilon_t+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}\Big)\Big]\Big)$$

Is there any mistake in the estimator?

Comment: I think $z_t$ is unobservable, so your estimator that includes $z_t$ is infeasible.

Comment: Is WN following a Normal Distribution? If so your process is a Moving-Average process

Comment: Roland, the mistake is that your estimator is infeasible. You physically cannot apply it. What else do you want to learn?

Comment: What properties do you want your estimator to have? Some models just cannot have good OLS estimators. OLS is not a universal estimation method.

Comment: What about $\hat\beta=(x'x)^{-1}x'y$?

Comment: Since it is a self-study question, maybe you could give a first shot at the variance yourself.

Comment: @RichardHardy But the estimator $\hat{\beta}=(x'x)^{-1}x'y$ is the least square estimator when you have random errors, but in this case there is no error but a noise. It will be the same?

Comment: What will be the same? The estimator is the same if you choose it to be. But the properties of the estimator will not be the same as in the case of i.i.d. errors.

Comment: Any progress? Let's not waste your bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation of the ordinary least-squares (OLS) estimator is incorrect, since you have treated the error term $z_t$ as if it were part of the regression.  Fixing this should give you the standard formula for the OLS estimator for a regression with a single variable and known zero mean:

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum x_t Y_t}{\sum x_t^2}.$$

To obtain the variance of this estimator, we first note that your error series $\boldsymbol{Z} \equiv \{ Z_t | t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is an MA($1$) process with covariance terms:

$$\mathbb{C}(Z_t, Z_{t+k}) = \begin{cases} 
      1+\theta^2 & \text{for } k = 0, \\[4pt]
      \theta & \text{for } k = 1, \\[4pt]
      0 & \text{for } k > 1. 
   \end{cases}$$

Since $Y_t = Z_t + \text{const}$ this gives you:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{V} \Bigg( \sum_{t=1}^n x_t Y_t \Bigg) = \mathbb{V} \Bigg( \sum_{t=1}^n x_t Z_t \Bigg)  &= \sum_{t=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^n x_t x_r \mathbb{C} (Z_t, Z_r) \\[6pt]
&= (1+\theta^2) \sum_{t=1}^n x_t^2 +  2 \theta \sum_{t=1}^{n-1} x_t x_{t+1}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

You then have:

$$\mathbb{V}(\hat{\beta}) = \frac{(1+\theta^2) \sum_{t=1}^n x_t^2 +  2 \theta \sum_{t=1}^{n-1} x_t x_{t+1}}{(\sum_{t=1}^n x_t^2)^2}.$$

Comment: Dear @Ben I have a question on unit root ADF test with quadratic trend. Can you please look at my question. I will be very happy and all helps will be much appreciated. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589970/deriving-adf-unit-root-test-form-for-the-time-series-with-quadratic-deterministi