# Temporary shock in VAR system

Tags: time-series, self-study, vector-autoregression

I have the following bivariate VAR system
\begin{align*}
z_t & = a_{11} z_{t-1} + a_{12} v_{t-1} + b_{11} z_{t-2} + b_{12} v_{t-2}+u_{zt}\\
v_t & = \gamma z_t + a_{21} z_{t-1} + a_{22} v_{t-1} + b_{21} z_{t-2} + b_{22} v_{t-2}+u_{vt},
\end{align*}

where $z_t$ and $v_t$ are stochastic variables and $\text{cov}(u_{vt}, u_{zt})=0$.

Using this structural form, I want to find the effect of one unit temporary shock to $z$ at time $t$ on $z$ and $v$ at time $(t+2)$.

How can I find this effect?

Comment: You should look into Impulse Response Functions (IRFs). They allow you to estimate the effects of shocks in a VAR/VECM system. If your VAR system is stable, the IRFs should converge to zero after a few time periods. They will also show the effect of shock on both variables at the time "t + 2".

Comment: @SpurEconomics Unless the autogressive functions are long-memoried, in which case 'a few time periods' may be much longer than than the series length of a data set?

Comment: @SpurEconomics indeed, I could not convert this system to impulse response functions ( MA($\infty$) form. How can I convert this system? Thank you so much.

Comment: If you show your suggestion more explicitly, I will be glad. @SpurEconomics because I really could not do.

Comment: @Alexis this is indeed a specific case where estimating the IRFs is problematic. May I suggest a different approach to IRFs, it might be useful in your situation: https://ink.library.smu.edu.sg/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1502&context=soe_research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a purely linear algebra solution:

\begin{align*}
z_t & = a_{11} z_{t-1} + a_{12} v_{t-1} + b_{11} z_{t-2} + b_{12} v_{t-2}+u_{zt}\\
v_t & = \gamma z_t + a_{21} z_{t-1} + a_{22} v_{t-1} + b_{21} z_{t-2} + b_{22} v_{t-2}+u_{vt},
\end{align*}

This system can be re-written as this after subsituting $z_t$ back into the $v_t$ equation

\begin{equation}
x_t = 
\begin{bmatrix}
z_t\\
v_t
\end{bmatrix}
u_t = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{zt}\\
u_{vt}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} + \gamma a_{11} & a_{22} + \gamma a_{12}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12}\\
b_{21} + \gamma b_{11} & b_{22} + \gamma b_{12}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

$$x_t = a x_{t-1} + b x_{t-2} + u_{t}$$

$$x_{t+2} = a x_{t+1} + b x_{t} + u_{t+2} = a (a x_{t} + b x_{t-1} + u_{t+1}) + b x_{t} + u_{t+2}$$

$$= (aa + b)x_{t} + ab x_{t-1} + au_{t+1} + u_{t+2}$$

\begin{equation}
x_{t+2+shock} = (aa+b)\left(x_t + \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right) + ab x_{t-1} + au_{t+1} + u_{t+2}
\end{equation}

The effect of the shock is to increase $x_{t+2}$ by the following:

\begin{equation}
x_{t+2+shock} - x_{t+2} = (aa+b)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Check with a simulation in R:

```
a <- matrix(c(.1, .2, 
              .3, .4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

b <- matrix(c(.01, .02, 
              .03, .04), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

xt <- vector("list", length = 100)

xt[[1]] <- matrix(c(0,0), ncol = 1)
xt[[2]] <- matrix(c(0,0), ncol = 1)

ut <- vector("list", length = 100)

for (i in 1:100)
{
  ut[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(2, 0, 0.01), ncol = 1)
}

for (i in 3:100)
{
  xt[[i]] <- a %*% xt[[i-1]] + b %*% xt[[i-2]] + ut[[i]]
}

xtshock <- xt

xtshock[[50]] <- xtshock[[50]] + matrix(c(1,0), ncol=1)

for (i in 51:100)
{
  xtshock[[i]] <- a %*% xtshock[[i-1]] + b %*% xtshock[[i-2]] + ut[[i]]
}

xtshock[[52]] - xt[[52]]

(a %*% a + b) %*% matrix(c(1,0), ncol = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see.

Comment: Dear R Carnell , I also have a question on ADF Unit root test with quadratic deterministic trend. This question doesn’t attract attention even though I started a bounty. If you mind, can you please look at this question as well? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589970/deriving-adf-unit-root-test-form-for-the-time-series-with-quadratic-deterministi